# If Get-Date is between a date range

Tags: date, datetime, powershell, if-statement

Before we begin, a heads up, I'm a Powershell Noob.

I have some previous experience in VBS but again, by no stretch of the imagination am I a developer.

I have been asked to create a script that will require me to run a certain set of backup jobs (Full and Differential, for arguments sake) dependent on the day/time on the system. The only requirement I've been given is that it must be written using Powershell (and as an FYI, I work in a corporate environment so there will be heavy scrutiny from a "Risk Mitigation" perspective).

Effectively I need to create an If statement that will check the system date and time and run the "Full" backup job if the system determines the date is between Saturday at 20:00hrs and Sunday at 19:00hrs. 
At any other time it should run the "Differential" backup job.

I feel I'm competent enough to substitute in my variables but I really need some help with creating a statement that is capable of checking if "now" is between the specified day/times.

If anybody could offer any suggestions it'd be greatly appreciated!

Thanks again,
IT-Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an example. Below that are two links to the documentation on powershell comparison and logical operators.

```
$now = Get-Date

if (($now.DayOfWeek -eq [System.DayOfWeek]::Saturday -and $now.Hour -ge 20) -or ($now.DayOfWeek -eq [System.DayOfWeek]::Sunday -and $now.Hour -lt 19))
{
  Write-Host "Full backup"
}
else
{
  Write-Host "Diff backup"
}
```

[about_Logical_Operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847789.aspx)

[about_Comparison_Operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx)

Comment: Apologies for the delay in response! Thank you so much for your assistance, always appreciated.